# How to work for nested objects in Django REST Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django REST Framework. In my Django models, I have `Store` and `SimilarStore` models. Store has `similarstore_set` which has multiple similar stores, and each similar store has `store` column as a foreign key showing its `id`. However, I wanna show the store object's columns instead of just `id`.

Like you see the below API example, the store with `id` 7 has 3 similar stores, and as the similar store has `store` foreign key, it shows the matched store's id number. I wanna show its child columns instead of just `id` number.

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "status": "active",
        "businessName": "Ruby Claire Boutique",
            "similarstore_set": [
                {
                    "id": 1182,
                    "store": 7,     <--- wanna show the store's child columns
                },
                {
                    "id": 1208,
                    "store": 7,     <--- wanna show the store's child columns
                },
                {
                    "id": 1249,
                    "store": 7,     <--- wanna show the store's child columns
                }
            ]

    },
    ...
]
```

I'm trying to do that because when I show the detail page of store with `id` 7, I need to show the similar store's information in the store's detail page. However, I can't show enough information with just `id`.

I'm not sure if I'm approaching the way in the right direction. Can anyone help me about this?

**EDIT**

**serializers.py**

```
class SimilarStoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    store = StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = SimilarStore
        fields = ('id', 'store', )


class StoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    similarstore_set = SimilarStoreSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ('id', 'status', 'businessName', 'similarstore_set', )
```

**models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):

    status = CharField(...)
    businessName = CharField(...)
    ...


class SimilarStore(models.Model):

    store = ForeignKey(Store)
    ...
```

Comment: Can you please post your code for your models and serializers?

Comment: Your question not containing any relevant serializers, pls do add those

Comment: Updated the post with my codes. Can you check that for me? @slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question *incomplete*, I assume **`similarstore_set`** is a ***reverse relationship data***, and it's displayed with the help of ***nested serializer class***.
Here you can try two solutions,
1. Define another serializer for **`Store`** model and link it in particular serializer. [See this official doc for more info](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

2. Use **`depth`** attribute in `Similarstore` serializer's Meta class. [See the doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

---

**Example**
Using **`depth`**,

```
class SimilarStoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SimilarStore
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1


class TopLevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    similarstore_set = SimilarStoreSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = someModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

**UPDATE-1**
Add **`depth`** field in Meta class of **`SimilarStoreSerializer`**  as

```
class SimilarStoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # removed "store = StringRelatedField()"
    class Meta:
        model = SimilarStore
        fields = ('id', 'store', )
        depth = 1
```

---

**UPDATE-2**
Create a **StoreMinimalSerializer**, and define ***required fields*** according to your needs

```
class StoreMinimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = (add fields you want,)


class SimilarStoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    store = StoreMinimalSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = SimilarStore
        fields = ('id', 'store',)
```

Comment: Sorry for missing my codes. I just updated the post with my codes. Can you check that and edit your answer if there is anything needed to be for me?

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Comment: @JPG you should probably rename `TopLevelSerializer` to `StoreSerializer`.

Comment: @JPG that works thank you! By the way, is there a way that I can change `fields` of the store column that I got from the depth? By using `depth`, I can get all the columns in store, but I don't need all of them, so I was wondering if there is a way to do that

Comment: @Jay Pls check my `Update-2` section

Comment: @slider I'm considering it as an `example`, because updated answer contains relevent parts.

Comment: @JPG perfect! It helped a lot :) By the way, did you exclude `depth = 1` on **UPDATE-2** on purpose or by mistake?

Comment: depth will show **all**  FK relations, whereas a custom serializer will show *defined fields*

Comment: If we use CustomSerializer, we could **control** the output, whereas, depth can't